# forgot password/username Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I am building login/signup pages and it's work so perfectly.

But I just want to know how I can add a label or a button for the *"Forgot my password or username"* on the login page.

- I'd like to have a pop up message or an alert that allows the user to enter their Email

  - so in case their Email doesn't exist in the database there will pop a message that says, that this email is not correct or something
  - in case the email already exists in the database I want to send the username and a new password to the user.

Please note that I am using parse.

Thank you,

Comment: Please note this has nothing to with the `xcode IDE`

Comment: The default login page already has a "Forgot?" link that provides the functionality you want. Why don't you use it? Parse also provides examples on how to customize the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First display an alert view with type UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

```
  UIAlertView * forgotPassword=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forgot Password"      message:@"Please enter your email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
forgotPassword.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[forgotPassword textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate=self;
[forgotPassword show];
```

and in your alert view delegate

```
 if(buttonIndex ==1){
    NSLog(@"ok button clicked in forgot password alert view");
NSString *femailId=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    if ([femailId isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *display;
        display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Please enter password for resetting password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [display show];

    }else{
        [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:femailId block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            UIAlertView *display;
            if(succeeded){
                display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password email" message:@"Please check your email for resetting the password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            }else{
                display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Email doesn't exists in our database" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            }
            [display show];
        }];

    }
```

Comment: Really thanks that work, just one more additional question. how can I send a notification email to the user?

Comment: the best thing of parse.com is every time an user changes or requests for resetting the password an e-mail is sent by parse.com server automatically for verification or resetting the password